# Angular 9, how to filter over a table which has columns containing values with dots and slash?

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, angular-material, material-table

I have a table in my Angular 9 project in which there are two columns containg a date and IPs addresses.

This is my applyFilter method, but it works only on simple strings. When I try to filter on dates or IPs it doesn't work.

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

How can I fix it for filtering even on those two columns?

Comment: What your code shows you are only removing white spaces and converting to lowercase the string, which is obvious dates and IPs could be numbers hence converting them to lowercase makes no sense.

Comment: So what would you suggest instead? How can i exclude those points or slash during filtering operation?

Comment: I am still not understanding your requirements what you are trying to achieve filter means removing some certain data which we call filter out data etc. You can add column data and the expected data that will make more sense what you have and what you want after filter and it will help to put a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. You need to know they key you will be filtering (your table column).
2. Now that you have the key, pass it into the filter, so the function knows what to compare it with (in this case myKeyName).

   ```
   applyFilter(filterValue: string, myKeyName: string) {
   filterValue = filterValue.trim();
   filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
   this.datasource = this.datasource.filter(x => x[myKeyName] == filterValue);
   }
   ```

Comment: It gives me this error:
Filter term that should be used to filter out objects from the data array. To override how data objects match to this filter string, provide a custom function for filterPredicate.

Comment: I edited my answer, I wrote this at 5am. What we are missing here is the key you want to filter (the column in your table). You can replace the `x.value` by `x[key]` once you have the key.